# How to add the libxml framework in the iOS application?

Tags: ios

I am using the QuickBlox third party framework in my application.when i am using that application we added the  framework but unfortunately it is saying that "file not found". I searched so many procedures and also i followed the same way how they explained. Still i am  not able to getting the success the build
Please any one help me to resolve this error.

I am waiting for your valuable answers,Please respond quickly.

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Problem is when I added the libxml framework in the build phases that time i am trying to importing the
#import <libxml/tree.h>
Then it is saying the error "not found"
I am not using any other code for libxml framework.